# Why did I get an error at 'print(digits.images(0))' with the Wakari 'digits' dataset

Tags: machine-learning, svm, numpy

**context**

I want to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTeVOb8gaD4&index=2&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDd0flgGphKCej-9jp-QdzZ3) tutorial on machine learning in Python using Wakari.

At 7.07 minutes into the video I received a error:

**error text**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-9-1322bba20f1e> in <module>()

 10 print(digits.target)

 11 

---> 12 print(digits.images(0))



TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

**code/error screenshot**

[image]

**questions**

- Why did I get the error?
- How do I get around it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `digits.images[0]`. `digits.images` is a three dimensional array, not a function.